# How do you add trendline to part of data in ggplot2?

Tags: r, ggplot2, linear-regression, scatter, trendline

I have data and a plot like this,

```
x = c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12)
y1 = x^2-5
y2 = -x^2+1

data <- data.frame(x,y1,y2)
data1 = data.frame(pivot_longer(data,2:3))

ggplot(data1, aes(x, y = value, color = name))+ 
  geom_point()+
  geom_smooth(method = 'lm',se = FALSE)
```

[image: Output]

Is there a way to have the trendline only applying to values for x greater than a certain number, like 3?

Comment: It's ambiguous. Do you want to discard those data where `x<3` and fit a new trendline, or use all of the data to fit but trim the line where `x<3`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Similar to both above just using `subset`:

```
ggplot(data1, aes(x, y = value, color = name))+ 
  geom_point()+
  geom_smooth(data=subset(data1, x > 3), method = 'lm',se = FALSE)
```

[image]

Answer (score 4):

You can do this:

```
ggplot(data1, aes(x, y = value, color = name))+ 
  geom_point()+
  geom_smooth(data=dplyr::filter(data1,x>3), method = 'lm',se = FALSE)
```

[image: g3]

Comment: Can the line be easily extrapolated to go beyond the points plotted? As in, the line will be formed using only the points given, but an extrapolation will be shown.

Answer (score 2):

You can apply the current `aes` to `geom_point` only, and create a new column (i.e. `x2` in my code) for mapping to `geom_smooth`.

```r
library(tidyverse)
x = c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12)
y1 = x^2-5
y2 = -x^2+1

data <- data.frame(x,y1,y2)
data1 = data.frame(pivot_longer(data,2:3))

data1 %>% mutate(x2 = ifelse(x > 3, x, NA)) %>% 
  ggplot()+ 
  geom_point(aes(x, y = value, color = name)) +
  geom_smooth(aes(x2, y = value, color = name), method = 'lm',se = FALSE)
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2022-05-07 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>